# Is it possible to transfer all the data within an each loop in rails/erb?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, partials

I am trying to create an application where I have certain data about each message thread, but want to present that data in different spots on the page.  On my list of all messages side, I have the following code:

```
<div class="contactThreadList">
    <% @threads_data.each do |thread| %>
        // summary data regarding the thread
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Then, when the user clicks on a thread, more details show up on the other side of the page, kind of like a preview pane on Gmail or Yahoo.  However, I have already loaded all of the data onto the page and would rather not use a partial to refetch the data.  Would it be possible to use that same thread on another part of the page?  This is the code I am imagining:

**On another part of the page not in the contactThreadList div**

```
<div class="previewPane">
    <p><%= selectedthread.message %></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly.

To store loaded data you can do smth like

```
<div class="contactThreadList">
    <% @threads_data.each do |thread| %>
        <div id="thread_<%= thread.id %>" data-thread=<%= thread.to_json %> > 
           // summary data you want to display
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

then in js console try:

```
$("#thread_1").data("thread")
```

it will be parsed to js object.

But if you want lot's of such features, then better to use some of js frameworks like Angular, Ember, Backbone :)

Comment: JavaScript and JSON are NOT same.`$("#thread_1").data("thread")` will throw a string of thread object not message.

Comment: @User089247 Yes JavaScript and JSON are totally different entities, 100% :) But `$("#thread_1").data("thread")` will return javascript object, I've tested before posting. So `$("#thread_1").data("thread").message` will return you "message" propery

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, but if you have tested then I'll count on your words. But, for me, it's still not clear how JavaScript will automagically convert a string object into a JSON format.

Comment: @User089247 jQuery treats data given as `data(obj)` as the object itself. So since he is setting `data(obj)` to a JSON Object it will be treated as such. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Basically his syntax creates something like `$(dom_object).data("thread",JSON_OBJECT)`

Comment: Oh, interesting! I should make a note on that. Thanks for the clarification.